# Check if product is saleable, without product load

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization

There's the following code in my theme, that checks in a loop if products  are saleable:

```
foreach ($_products as $productId){
    $product = $_productModel->load($productId);
    if (!$product->isSaleable()){
        //...
    }
}
```

How should I change this and remove load() function?

Comment: where does the `$_products` variable come from?

Comment: @Marius $_products, is an array of product ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $_products))
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents();
//if you need only enabled and visible products uncomment the 2 lines below
//Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
//Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    if (!$product->isSaleable()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: collection is not including disabled products. No matter if I use product_status or not. Do you know why?

Comment: Does this code need to change in case product flat data is enabled?

Comment: I think you don't get the disabled products because flat catalog is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The `isSaleable()` information is always part of product collections (no need to add price data).

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addIdFilter($_products)
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    if (!$product->isSaleable()) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the $_products was the collection of some products. Try to add **price** attribute to current select collection.

```
$_products->addAttributeToSelect('price');
foreach ($_products as $productId){
    if (!$product->isSaleable()){
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: $_products, is just an array of product ids